# Feed Publisher Community and Locker Service

Tags: community, locker-service, chatter-feed

Locker Service is about to be automatically activated in Summer 17.

Does someone know what is going to happen with the feed publisher component in the community template ? Today, if activated it is impossible to use the rich text area and though to publish anything...

Are they going to update the feed component or everything will be broken in Summer 17 ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A safeharbor before i begin .But yes as soon as new release is rolled out salesforce is working to make the rich text area lightning locker complaint .If they are unable to do so, we will have option to disable them in the PROD .

Official words from salesforce for reference

[image]

Also if you access to partner community you can read further here

https://partners.salesforce.com/partnerAlert?id=a033A00000FtHBjQAN

Specifically this

> Q: With the LockerService critical update, are there any limitations?

Exclusively in Sandbox and Developer orgs, when LockerService is activated you can't edit rich-text fields and the fields are grayed out. This limitation will be addressed before LockerService is auto-enabled during the Summer ‘17 release. Rich-text editors in production orgs continue to function normally even when LockerService is activated.

Comment: Thank you Mohith this is exactly what I was looking for!